# sequence of independent equally distributed random variables

Tags: probability-theory

Give an example of a sequence of independent equally distributed random variables $\{X_n\}_{n > 1}$ such that $\frac{S_n}{n} \stackrel{\mathbb{P}}{\longrightarrow} 0$, but with probability 1, $\liminf_{n \to \infty} \frac{S_n}{n} = -\infty$, $\limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{S_n}{n} = +\infty$.

Comment: @AlvinL typo, it means Convergence in measure

Comment: What is $S_n$? Is it $\sum_{k=1}^nX_k$?

Comment: Could look for a symmetric rv such that $E|X| = \infty$. Cauchy won't do, because then $S_n/n$ does not converge to $0$ in probability. $E|X|<\infty$ won't do either, because then strong LLN implies $S_n/n\to 0$ a.s.

Comment: @Will yes, it is

Comment: @AlvinL Yes, I thought of it too, but there's still no specific example.